# Bitbake is failing for yocto build

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to compile yocto code with bitbake and everytime it is getting failed at same place (`elfutils_0.166.bb:do_compile`) with exit code 1.

Once it built the code completely fine, then for confirmation I tried to do clean build and it got failed again at the same place.

```
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| ../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/dwfl_report_elf.c: In function ‘__libdwfl_elf_address_range’:
| ../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/dwfl_report_elf.c:172:19: error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]
|        add_p_vaddr = true;
|                    ^
| ../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/dwfl_report_elf.c:174:5: note: here
|      case ET_DYN:
|      ^~~~
| gcc  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLOCALEDIR='"/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/locale"' -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I..  -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/lib -I.. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libelf -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libebl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdw -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdwelf -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -Wlogical-op -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference -Werror -Wunused -Wextra -Wstack-usage=262144  -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o derelocate.o ../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/derelocate.c
| gcc  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLOCALEDIR='"/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/locale"' -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I..  -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/lib -I.. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libelf -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libebl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdw -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdwelf -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -Wlogical-op -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference -Werror -Wunused -Wextra -Wstack-usage=262144  -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o offline.o ../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/offline.c
| gcc  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLOCALEDIR='"/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/locale"' -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I..  -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/lib -I.. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libelf -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libebl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdw -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdwelf -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -Wlogical-op -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference -Werror -Wunused -Wextra -Wstack-usage=262144  -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o segment.o ../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/segment.c
| gcc  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLOCALEDIR='"/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/locale"' -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I..  -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/lib -I.. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libelf -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libebl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdw -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdwelf -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -Wlogical-op -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference -Werror -Wunused -Wextra -Wstack-usage=262144  -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o dwfl_module_info.o ../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/dwfl_module_info.c
| gcc  -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLOCALEDIR='"/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/locale"' -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I..  -I. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/lib -I.. -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libelf -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libebl -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdw -I../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/../libdwelf -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wold-style-definition -Wstrict-prototypes -Wlogical-op -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference -Werror -Wunused -Wextra -Wstack-usage=262144  -isystem/data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o dwfl_getmodules.o ../../elfutils-0.166/libdwfl/dwfl_getmodules.c
| cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
| Makefile:584: recipe for target 'dwfl_report_elf.o' failed
| make[2]: *** [dwfl_report_elf.o] Error 1
| make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| Makefile:479: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
| make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
| Makefile:395: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| WARNING: /data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/elfutils-native/0.166-r0/temp/run.do_compile.107012:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /data/vamshi/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/elfutils-native/0.166-r0/temp/log.do_compile.107012)
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/data/vamshi/yocto/oss/genivi-12/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/elfutils/elfutils_0.166.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 263 tasks of which 0 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  virtual:native:/data/vamshi/yocto/oss/genivi-12/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/elfutils/elfutils_0.166.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 8 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: This is missing all the details necessary to help (e.g. actual error message, yocto version). The elfutils version makes me guess that this is a fairly old yocto at least...

Comment: I have added the complete error

Comment: You can try the following [patch](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/141146/) or [this one](https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/140563/)